# Git - Updating my branch with code from others

Tags: git

I am working on a project with several other developers. We are all working on different parts of the project and are using Git for source control. I am very new to Git.

My work is being done in a separate branch (called `EncryptionEngine`) off of our main `development` branch. As I work on my branch I want to pull in the code that the other developers check into the `development` branch so I don't get to far out of sync with what they are doing.

I don't want to merge my code to the `development` branch until it is complete. How do I go about pulling in their changes into my branch without committing my changes to the `development` branch.

Comment: Just pull the latest changes and merge development into your branch. Or rebase your branch with the latest development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should merge their branch into your own like this (while you're still using your own branch):

```
git merge development
```

Comment: Do I need to `checkout` development first or can I execute this command while in my own branch?

Comment: you should do this while you're in your own branch. Updated the answer with this info.

Comment: Thanks! I see other posts mentioning `rebase` along with `merge` so I was not sure which one to go with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge specific commits, check out the [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `git rebase`. I recommend reading [this article](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/09/14/dont-be-scared-of-git-rebase/) and [the man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) if you want to go further.

`git rebase development` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the article links